# How to debug Android build that crashes instantly?

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I have a React Native Android app (.67) that works perfectly on emulator and in debug mode (through Android Studio). However, when I build the app, it just instantly crashes on startup. I have zero clue where to even start troubleshooting. How do you access the stacktrace? How do you troubleshoot apps that don't give any meaningful errors at all?

What files should I post here for inspection? I'm not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The best debugging tool you can use for Android is the logcat in the Android Studio.
Connect your phone to the system via a USB
open the logcat terminal
Add the filter of your app's package name (so that it only shows logs of your app.)
Check the logs for crashes.

Comment: ...and I can do that for installed bundles?

Comment: Yes you can
Logcat shows the log of the entire application running, we can filter the logs based on its package name.

Comment: Interesting. I'm getting an okhttp error (but I never changed anything). Do you happen to know how to flush the dependencies of a React Native project? I don't know why all of a sudden external images can't be loaded in React Native Elements' Image library without changing anything...

Comment: Hey Joel, I need to check how to flush the dependencies of RN project.but if in any sense my answer helped you. Please give me an upvote✌️